# How to change the background color of a DIV from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to change the background color of a DIV based on the end-user's selection from a drop down list? For example, I have a drop down menu with  options for blue, green, red, etc. and I would like the DIV background color to be whatever the user selects. Here is what i tried but I cannot figure out how to get it it work:

```
<head>

<style>
div.results{
position: relative;
left: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: black;
}
</style>

<script>// this script will place the background image.

function selectBackground(){
    var e = document.getElementById("selector");
    var BackgroundValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style.background-color= BackgroundValue;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="selectors">
    <select id=selector>
        <option>Select Background</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select>   
<button onclick="selectBackground()">Preview Results</button>
</div>

<div class="results" id="PreviewResults" style="background-color:white;">
Results Here
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style.background-color= BackgroundValue;
```

This doesn’t work, because what you have here would a *subtraction operation* in JavaScript, because `-` is the operator for that.

To access any style properties that contain `-` you need to either remove the `-` and replace the following letter with its uppercase version:

```
document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style.backgroundColor = BackgroundValue;
```

or use the square bracket syntax:

```
document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style["background-color"] = BackgroundValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `style.backgroundColor` to actually set your background :

```
document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style.background-color= BackgroundValue;
```

You also may want to consider setting the value of your default option to `transparent` (the initial value for the background) so that the user could switch back after a change was made :

```
<select id=selector>
    <option value="transparent">Select Background</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/cariwu/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

`document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style.background-color= BackgroundValue;`

to

`document.getElementById("PreviewResults").style.backgroundColor = BackgroundValue;`