# Trying to change the gradient background with a drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, background-color

I'm trying to figure out how I would get the drop down menu to change the color of the "Red Gradient Bar" upon color selection, but I'm a bit lost.

```
<div>
        <select>
            <option value="choose">Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help! Here is the jfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/p9thm6af/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the background color of a DIV from a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525391/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-div-from-a-dropdown-menu)

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color

Comment: This one too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664678/how-can-change-the-div-background-color-when-dropdown-select

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those are able to use the "CSS Gradient" , but the first is pretty much what I want to do.